# How to make these buttons act as a link?

Tags: html, css, frontend

So I am trying to create a profile page for my website and there are multiple buttons that should link to various parts of the website. I created buttons in the following way:

```
<br>
<div style="text-align:center;">
    <br>
    <input class='button1' type='button' value='Profile'/>
    <input class='button1' type='button' value='My Messages'/>
    <br>
    <input class='button1' type='button' value='Create New Listing'/>
    <input class='button1' type='button' value='My Listings'/>
    <br>
    <input class='button1' type='button' value='My Bids'/>
    <input class='button1' type='button' value='My Purchases'/>
    <input class='button1' type='button' value='My Favorite Listings'/>
</body>
</html>
```

How can I add links to these buttons?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create an HTML button that acts like a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906582/how-to-create-an-html-button-that-acts-like-a-link)

Comment: If you want a link, use [a link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a). Apply CSS to make it look the way you want.

Comment: You can but the whole input inside an a tag. However I would advise you to use JS to write your own click handler.

Comment: @Wimanicesir — No. `input` elements are **not allowed** inside `a` elements.

Comment: @Wimanicesir — Using JS to write a click handler will not make it behave like a link. e.g. You can't right click and pick "open in new tab".

Comment: @Quentin, Yes you can actually do that with JS.  window.open(url, '_blank') and change the right click behaviour to open that menu. There is actually almost nothing that can't be done with JS that is done by HTML.

Comment: @Wimanicesir — That isn't what I said. A link gives the **user** the **choice** to right click and get a context menu that has that open.

Comment: @Quentin, like I said. You can mimic the right click behaviour as well. And show the menu it would show on a link. Putting things into bold when not reading it good yourself is a bit funny :p

Comment: There are a dozen or so menu items on my link context menu. You can't replicate most of them with JS.

Answer (score 0):

You're using the wrong HTML elements, which is why they won't behave the way you want.

In HTML, a link is defined using the `<a href='XXX'>Link text</a>` tag. If you change your `input` elements to `a` elements, you'll get them to work as you want.

The next step is then to make the link look the way you want, and you can achieve this using CSS (probably the `background`, `color` and `border` properties).